# How to horizontally align lines of text?

Tags: html, css

Suppose we have the following:

```
Label: Some text

Longer label: Other text
```

Is there a way to get the text after the colon aligned? Eg;

```
Label:          Some text

Longer label:   Other text
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of archiving that, this one is using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

We created a class called `aligned` which will be a flexbox container, `flex-direction` allows us to specify the direction of the elements inside the tag with this class, in this case `flex-direction: row` since we want the elements inside to be displayed horizontally.

Then, for each `<p>` inside the divs with the `.aligned` class ( this is done using `.aligned > p` in CSS ) we'll set a defined `min-width`, and a `margin` for each `<p>`.

```html
<style>
  .aligned {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  .aligned > p{
    min-width: 14%;
    margin: 1%;
  }
</style>

<div class="aligned">
  <p>
    Label:
  </p>
  <p>
    Some text
  </p>
   <p>
    Some text
  </p>
</div>

<div class="aligned">
  <p>
    Longer label:
  </p>
  <p>
    Other text
  </p>
  <p>
    Other text
  </p>
</div>
```

Or, you can also use tables:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Label:</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Longer Label:</td>
    <td>Other text</td>
    <td>Other text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```